# AutoFixture Build-Freeze-Create sequence

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

I just noticed, that whenever I do `Freeze` on a fixture in-between `Build<>()`-`Create()` calls that `Freeze`s do not get applied. Is it intended behavior of AutoFixture or a bug?

To make things clear:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization())
var builder = fixture.Build<SomeType>();
fixture.Freeze<Mock<ISomeInterface>>().Setup(m => m.SomeProperty).Returns(10);
var sut = builder.Create();
// if SomeType uses ISomeInterface.SomeProperty it will get 0 returned - *incorrect*
```

this works fine:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization())
fixture.Freeze<Mock<ISomeInterface>>().Setup(m => m.SomeProperty).Returns(10);
var sut = fixture.Create<SomeType>();
// if SomeType uses ISomeInterface.SomeProperty it will get 10 returned - correct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you freeze before calling the builder

Freeze-Build-Create sequence

```
[TestClass]
public class AutoFixtureTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void _FreezeBuildCreate() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = 10;
        var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        fixture.Freeze<Mock<ISomeInterface>>().Setup(m => m.SomeProperty).Returns(expected);
        var builder = fixture.Build<SomeType>();
        var sut = builder.Create();

        //Act
        var actual = sut.GetA();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    public class SomeType {
        private ISomeInterface a;
        public SomeType(ISomeInterface a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
        public int GetA() {
            return a.SomeProperty;
        }
    }

    public interface ISomeInterface {
        int SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If you look at the definition of the `Build` method

> Customizes the creation algorithm for a single object, effectively
>   turning off all Customizations on the Ploeh.AutoFixture.IFixture.

If build is called before the freeze all customizations after that would not take effect.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I actually solved this problem another way - with custom events being called between Build-Create so I can keep the sequence somewhere where it does not interfere with `Freeze`s

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I solved this issue by myself. Since I didn't have much choice in choosing where `Build`-`Create` are placed, had to use events for this. Oh, and I didn't want to make `Create` virtual.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
public class BaseSutBuilder<TSut> {
    // other weird stuff...

    // somewhere in ctor:
    protected BaseSutBuilder() {
        SutBuilders = _ => {};
    }

    protected Action<ICustomizationComposer<TSut>> SutBuilders { get; }

    public TSut Create() {
        var builder = _fixture.Build<TSut>();
        SutBuilders(builder);
        return builder.Create();
    }
}

public class SomeTypeSutBuilder: BaseSutBuilder<SomeType> {
    public SomeTypeSutBuilder() {
        SutBuilders += c => c.With(.......
        SutBuilders += c => c.With(.......
    }
}
```